# Does a user's experience/qualification matter when answering?

Tags: discussion

I have recently finished my undergraduate degree, and will join a graduate degree in Fall 2021. I have hung around the main site long enough (even before I became a member) that I (kind of) know what questions make sense there<sup>1</sup>, and I (kind of) know what sort of answers are useful.

This means that when I try and answer questions, it is not always from personal experience or any citable source, but sometimes draws from other answers I have read on the main site (and find useful). Some of my answers may seem as though written by someone way more senior than "just a graduate student", as though I know absolutely everything I'm talking about, but they do usually draw from other answers on the site.

I do this because *I can*, because I (kind of) *know* what answers will be given by other, more senior users, based on previous answers I have read. However, I would rather that no one thinks I am "just a graduate student" and have no idea what I'm talking about. Whatever I answer is based either on personal experience or on something I know makes sense, because I've read similar answers before.

For instance, I have answered questions on uploading to arXiv after acceptance and on Mathematics GRE for an engineering course, since I have been through the same problems before. On the other hand, I have also answered questions on whether a Ph.D. student should mail another researcher from his country, on whether a summer project abroad makes sense for graduate studies and on poor undergraduate grades for Ph.D. admissions. These are, in general, much better answered by those in a more senior position with experience of how these things work. I have answered them however, because I can guess what the accepted (or highest voted) answer will say.

Is this okay, and does it make sense to continue doing this or should I defer to someone with actual experience?

---

<sup>1: Meta is a different beast, but I guess I'll find out now.</sup>